# Why use this obj.method.call(obj, arg) and not obj.method(arg)?

Tags: javascript

I see this pattern sometimes...

```
obj.method.call(obj, arg)
```

and I don't understand why its different from...

```
obj.method(arg)
```

why use the first pattern?

My goodness, seems to have generated a lot of discussion :)

Just to clarify, I am only asking about the case when the object that the method is on is the same as the first argument of `call()` (or maybe @FelixKling put it better: when the *owner* is the same as the *receiver*).  I'm not asking about `obj.method.call(obj2, arg)`.

---

As mentioned below, even the case when the function is bound fails to differentiate the two methods.

```
o2={p2:3};
o={p1:(function(){return this.p2}).bind(o2), p2:2};
o.p1() === o.p1.call(o) // true
```

---

### Edit

I guess the source of this idiom is the pattern used to rebind an object's methods...

```
obj.method.apply(obj, arguments)
```

Comment: It's not different. Maybe the author didn't know better.

Comment: Sure it's different - conceptually. The question is about fn.call(scope, ...) vs scope.fn(...) generally. Even if the questioner posed it with examples that are equivalent, he's clearly asking about something more subtle here.

Comment: @alecmc: I guess we just have to wait until the OP clarifies that. As "clearly" as you see it this way, I "clearly" see it the other way.

Comment: @alecmce surely scope is not the issue? Scope is about _declaration context_, which is the same no?  `call()` is manipulation _invocation context_ and my question is about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why use this `obj.method.call(obj, arg)` and not `obj.method(arg)`?

There is no practical reason to do this.

In both cases `this` will refer to `obj`, assuming the function is not bound to a different value (in which case `this` will always be the bound value anyway).

Comment: Does this pattern have a name I wonder?  What would you call it if you were to google it?

Comment: I don't think there is a name for that.

Comment: yes... `o={p1:(function(){return this.p2}).bind(o2), p2:2}; o2={p2:3}; o.p1() === o.p1.call(o) // true` so still no difference.

Comment: hmm, it's a pity you can't do regular expression searches on google

Answer (score 3):

No difference in the examples you post. However, `obj1.method.call(obj2, arg)` lets you change `this` inside the method. `obj.method.apply(obj, args)` lets you have variable argument count.

For example, `[].slice.call(arguments)` (and its superior, `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)`) is a common idiom that calls `slice` from an array on the non-array (`arguments`) receiver.

Comment: Why wouldn't you do `obj[methodname](arg)` ?

Comment: @FelixKling: Because I am an idiot. :D Yeah, good point. Will edit.

Comment: I'm relatively sure the OP knows the advantages of `.call` and `.apply` and only asks for that specific use case, where the "owner" is the same as the receiver.

Comment: @zerkms: Actually, yes, they might do different things, if someone does something silly: `var foo = function() { console.log("foo"); }; foo.call = function() { console.log("bar"); }` will result in `foo()` printing "foo", but `foo.call(foo)` printing "bar".

Comment: Upvoted for right answer. This is strange, I also added the right answer (even first) but I have 2 downvotes, oh god why :)

Comment: Thanks and yes, I'm only asking about the one case. By the way, doesn't `[].slice.call(arguments)` cause V8 optimisation to break?

Comment: @CoolBlue: It does. But the alternative is clunky and almost no-one cares (or knows) enough not to do it the simple way. So, yes, common idiom.

Comment: Interesting, personally I think it's good that the idiom is common coz it puts pressure on to make it OK.  The V8 guys are _smart_ so they will no doubt get it sorted...

Answer (score -2):

In case of first pattern inside the method `this` variable would point on `obj` variable:

```
obj.method.call(obj, arg)
```

Variable `this` in the second case would point in the parent variable, mostly it is a `window` variable.
You can checkout that doing the following in the console:

```
var
  num = 1,
  pass = "Test",
  myFunc = function(expArg) {
    console.log(expArg);
    console.log(this);
  };

myFunc(pass);
// You would get "Test" and reference of window variable
myFunc.call(num, pass);
// You would get "Test" and number object with value of 1.
```

Comment: And in case of second?

Comment: "Variable this in the second case would point in the parent variable, mostly it is a window variable." --- are you sure?

Comment: @zerkms added explanation. depends on where you declare the function, if it is global, then it is `window`.

Comment: Your examples don't match with the OP's example. They are talking about "method calls", not "function calls". Given, `obj.method(arg)`, `this` will always refer to `obj`, unless it was bound to a different value.

Comment: @FelixKling This is just an example. I wrote an explanation at the top.

Comment: The point is that in the second example, `this` will refer to `obj` as well. This question is not about `.call`. It's about the difference between two examples provided. You make it sound like there is a difference where there is not.

Comment: @FelixKling and my answer is wrong? Am I lying saying that using `.call` he can change `this` variable?

Comment: What you say is (partly) correct, but not every correct statement answers the question. "The sky is blue" is also a correct statement, but does not answer this question. I say partly, because *"Variable `this` in the second case would point in the parent variable,"* is not correct. In the second case, `this` *will* refer to `obj`, just like the first case.

Comment: @FelixKling I think you haven't fully read my previous comment.

Comment: @zerkms >parent variable. in this case of course it is `obj` variable, because `method` is its property!