# obj.method(argument)

Tags: ruby, object, methods

I am looking at this code:

```
class Student 
  attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name, :age
  def initialize(first, last, age)
    @first_name = first
    @last_name = last
    @age = age
  end

  def birthday
    @age += 1
  end
end

class ViewStudent
  def initialize(student)
    @student = student
  end

  def do_something
    puts "Student name: #{@student.first_name} #{@student.last_name}"
  end
end

class UpdateStudent
  def initialize(student)
    @student = student
  end

  def do_something
    puts "What is the student's first name?"
    @student.first_name = gets.chomp
    puts "What is the student's last name?"
    @student.last_name = gets.chomp
    puts "Updated student: #{@student.first_name} #{@student.last_name}"
  end
end

choices = [ViewStudent, UpdateStudent]

student = Student.new("John", "Doe", 18)

puts "Select 1 to view student or 2 to update student."
selection = gets.chomp.to_i
obj = choices[selection - 1]
obj = obj.new(student)
obj.do_something
```

In the last five lines, I understand that `selection = gets.chomp.to_i` converts the selection options to integers, but how does that work in tandem with `obj = choices[selection - 1]`?

I'm also not sure what `obj = obj.new(student)` and `obj.do_something` do. It looks like a local variable is being set to create a new object with student as the argument. However, `obj` isn't a class or method to call on?

I can also gather that `obj.do_something` calls the methods defined for both `ViewStudent` and `UpdateStudent` given the selection.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30838044), but it doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`obj = choices[selection - 1]` just select `ViewStudent` if 1 and `UpdateStudent` if 2 from your array by index (choices[0] or choices[1]).

Then you creating an instance of selected class (`ViewStudent.new` or `UpdateStudent.new`) and call `do_something` method on this instance, because this methos difined in both classes:

```
obj = choices[selection - 1] # obj is ViewStudent or UpdateStudent class
obj = obj.new(student) # obj is ViewStudent or UpdateStudent instance
obj.do_something # call `do something` method on instance
```

Comment: Thank you! I forgot about the negative/reverse way to count back in an array.

As for the obj = obj.new(student) and obj.do_something is that when you mean by creating an instance of the selected class?

Comment: @AlexPho: it's good that you remembered it now, but reverse indexing has nothing to do with this. The `- 1` is there to convert 1-based user input (1 or 2) to 0-based array index (0 or 1)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I see, in theory with this conversion to (0 or 1) it would not be possible to add a third or even fourth choice. Correct?

Comment: @AlexPho: why not? Do you understand how the conversion happens?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Hmm I'm exactly sure, but I do understand that in an array e.g.

[banana, apple, grapes] the values would be 0, 1, 2 naturally.

Comment: @AlexPho: yep, exactly.